# Подскажите в чем проблема моего кода ? Мне нужно удалять все элементы массива кроме чисел

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
let array = [NaN, 0, 77, false, -17, '', undefined, 99, null];

function filterFalse(arr) {
  let arr2 = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
      arr2.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return arr2;
  }
}

console.log(filterFalse(array));
```

Comment: В консоле выадет [NaN]

Comment: return вынесите из цикла. А NaN правильно - это number

Comment: Так и сделал. Но нужно было оставить только числа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю воспользоваться методом [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
let array = [NaN, 0, 77, false, -17, '',undefined, 99, null];

let newArray = array.filter(elem => typeof(elem) == "number" && !isNaN(elem));
console.log(newArray);
```

Результат будет таким:

```
[0, 77, -17, 99]
```

UPD: чуть более универсальное решение, исключающее не только нечисловые значения и NaN, но и Infinity

```
let array = [NaN, 0, 77, false, -17, '',undefined, 99, null];

let newArray = array.filter(elem => typeof(elem) == "number" && isFinite(elem));
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Не за что, спрашивайте ещё)